# Handling PHP Request in same Page

Tags: php, html, post

I am trying to handle the Post request in the same page. But i am facing some issues when handling post parameters.I am always getting 'value as empty'.

Below is my code.

```
<body>
    <?php include 'Header.html' ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="margin:10% 30% 0% 30%;">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h4 align="center" style="font-family: monospace;"><p>Upload External Device Report</p></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="container col-lg-12">
                        <form class="form-horizontal" action="UploadExternalReport.php" role="form" method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="file" class="filestyle" data-buttonName="btn-primary" name="fileToUpload" accept=".xls ,.xlsx" required="required" >
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
   // require_once '../PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    if(isset($_POST["fileToUpload"]) && trim($_POST["fileToUpload"]) != ""){
    echo $_POST['fileToUpload'];
    }
    else
    {
        echo'value is empty';
    }?>
```

I tried !empty($_POST["fileToUpload"]) in if condition. But still its getting as 'value is empty'.

Comment: what does `if(isset($_POST["fileToUpload"]) && trim($_POST["fileToUpload"]) != ""){` exactly mean?

Comment: That's not how you should check whether a file has been uploaded or not. Besides, use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function to check whether a file has been uploaded or not, so your `if` condition should be like this: `if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to use the $_FILES array, not $_POST.
So make use of $_FILES['fileToUpload'].

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php